# Send HTTP Request

Tags: inno-setup, httprequest

Is there any way to send HTTP request using (pure) Inno Setup?

isxdl.dll isn't an option, because it creates window of the "download".

Also I would like to avoid using curl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This extension can download without a UI; http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=50 (Via `ITD_DownloadFiles`)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`WinHttpRequest` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttprequest):

```pascal
var
  WinHttpReq: Variant;
begin
  WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
  WinHttpReq.Open('GET', 'https://www.example.com/', False);
  WinHttpReq.Send('');
  if WinHttpReq.Status <> 200 then
  begin
    Log(Format('HTTP error: %d %s', [Integer(WinHttpReq.Status), WinHttpReq.StatusText]));
  end
    else
  begin
    Log(Format('HTTP Response: %s', [WinHttpReq.ResponseText]));
  end;
end;
```